# Add another table to SQL results

Tags: mysql, sql

I am cracking my brain on this problem. I am trying to add data from another table to existing sql query:

```
Table Alfa (AA, AB, AC)


Table Zulu (ZA, ZB)
```

My existing query:

```
SELECT AB
     , ROUND(AVG(AC),0) AS Srednia
     , COUNT(AC) AS Uzyt 
  FROM Alfa 
 WHERE AA = %s 
 GROUP 
    BY AB 
 ORDER 
    BY AB ASC
```

How Can I add ZB to results if ZA=AB?

Comment: Have you looked at `JOIN` ?

Comment: Yes, I was able to do it in another query but is it possible to do it in only one?

Comment: `JOIN` is a way of combinining things into one query.

Comment: @Piotrek what do mean "but is it possible to do it in only one" ?

Comment: @GrishaLevit: only in one query (sorry I'm a bit sleepy!). I can do it in two separate queries (the one I presented and another, separate one with inner join), but i am having problems combining everything into single query...So the results from the presented query plus ZB results using INNER JOIN and ZULU table

Comment: You have answers suggesting something equivalent to: change your FROM clause to `FROM Alfa a INNER JOIN Zulu z ON z.ZA = a.AB` and then include extra columns from z (which I've set as the alias to `Zulu`) as needed. If this is not actually what you need, it will help tremendously to provide a few sample rows for each table and the expected results of your query given those rows.

Comment: ***WARNING*** Your existing query is subject to SQL injection attacks. It will be a security risk if you fail to sanitise `%s`.

Comment: Is the problem solved or do you still need more assistance?

Comment: @MikaelPuusaari thank you - your answer helped me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
SELECT a.AB, ROUND(AVG(a.AC),0) AS Srednia, COUNT(a.AC) AS Uzyt, Z.ZB FROM Alfa A 
INNER JOIN Zulu Z ON A.AB = Z.ZA
WHERE A.AA = %s
GROUP BY A.AB ORDER BY A.AB ASC
```

Comment: Puusari Thank you

Comment: the results only show if A.AB = Z.ZA 
How to edit query to show results (A.AA, A.AB, A.AC) even if Z.ZA is empty?

Comment: Change INNER JOIN TO LEFT JOIN, since your A-table is on the left side in the query

Comment: I changed my last comment, I noticed you wanted the A results

Comment: Almost there! Just now value of "Uzyt" is doubled. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you mean Uzyt is showing in two columns? If so, you need to group by the unique column that uzyt is using.. so try changing to GROUP BY A.AB, A.AC

Comment: Sorry, "COUNT(a.AC) AS Uzyt" value is doubled so instead 1 it shows 2, instead 2 shows 4 etc. 
It happens only when A.AB and Z.ZA are both present. (their values are the same, but column names different) 
If Z.ZA is null then values are ok - it looks like COUNT is counting both A.AB and Z.ZA?

Comment: @ Mikael Puusaari Oh and I would like to THANK YOU VERY MUCH for your help. You saved me so much time and frustration!!!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help out

Answer (score 0):

You'd put the subquery in the from clause as a derived table:

```
SELECT
  a.AB,
  a.Srednia,
  a.Uzyt,
  z.ZB
FROM
(
  SELECT AB
       , ROUND(AVG(AC),0) AS Srednia
       , COUNT(AC) AS Uzyt 
    FROM Alfa 
   WHERE AA = %s 
   GROUP BY AB 
) a
JOIN Zulu z ON z.ZA = a.AB
ORDER BY a.AB ASC;
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution!